# How does web3.eth.estimateGas does its estimation?

Tags: web3js, transactions, gas, power-consumption

I looked at https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/develop/dist/web3.js but can not find the method which it uses to estimate the amount of gas a transaction is going to consume.

Does anybody know how this works or can point to a reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web3.js library makes a call [`eth_estimategas`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_estimategas) to the ethereum client.

Geth will execute the transaction and will return the gas consumed, but it will discard any modification.

A note from the documentation

> Note that the estimate may be significantly more than the amount of gas actually used by the transaction, for a variety of reasons including EVM mechanics and node performance.

[Metamask's VM subprovider](https://github.com/MetaMask/provider-engine/blob/160a57b394e3a1c7c27a6c2d235fd7b932be9292/subproviders/vm.js#L66-L106)  also implements estimate gas by executing the transaction and measuring the gas consumed.

Comment: Do the estimate also cost gas?

Comment: @wong2 It doesn't not cost, it is calculated off-chain.